# Android: How to know when device is locked and unlocked

Tags: android, background, broadcastreceiver, screen, lockscreen

I'm developing an app which has background processes, few of the features in my app shall only work if user turn on the screen and also unlock the "Lock Screen". There are actions for **SCREEN_ON**, **SCREEN_OFF** and **USER_PRESENT**.

I reset a flag on **SCREEN_OFF** event and set it on **USER_PRESENT** event, this works fine but here I have another issue;
In settings there is an options "Lock instantly with power button", if it is unchecked, device will not lock until 5 seconds of sleep.

Now, SCREEN_OFF event is called and USER_PRESENT event is never called, if user turn off screen and turn it on within 5 seconds.

Is there is any action for USER_NOT_PRESENT or DEVICE_LOCKED so I can reset my flag there?

NOTE: I can work around if I know the settings **"lock_screen_lock_after_timeout"** and **"power_button_instantly_locks"**. However I can get **"lock_screen_lock_after_timeout"** settings as follow but don't know how to get **"power_button_instantly_locks"**

```
ContentResolver mResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
long timeout = Settings.Secure.getLong(mResolver, "lock_screen_lock_after_timeout", 0);
```

Thank you. Any other approach shall also be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Use reflection to get the setting value of `power_button_instantly_locks`.
See the code below:

```
/**
  *This function is used to detect the system setting: Power button instantly locks. To see whether this setting is enabled or not.
  * @return true if Power button instantly locks is enabled, otherwise, false.
  */

private boolean isPowerButtonInstantlyLocksOn(){
    String LOCK_PATTERN_UTILS="com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils";
    String POWER_BUTTON_INSTANTLY_LOCKS="getPowerButtonInstantlyLocks";
    boolean isPowerButtonInstantlyLocks=false;
    try{
        Class<?> lockPatternUtilsClass=Class.forName(LOCK_PATTERN_UTILS);
        Object lockPatternUtils=lockPatternUtilsClass.getConstructor(Context.class).newInstance(this);

        // According to the source code of Android 6, the function getPowerButtonInstantlyLocks is declared with a parameter "int userId"
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            Method method = lockPatternUtilsClass.getMethod(POWER_BUTTON_INSTANTLY_LOCKS,new Class[]{int.class});
            isPowerButtonInstantlyLocks=Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(method.invoke(lockPatternUtils,userID())));
        }else {
            Method method = lockPatternUtilsClass.getMethod(POWER_BUTTON_INSTANTLY_LOCKS);
            isPowerButtonInstantlyLocks=Boolean.valueOf(String.valueOf(method.invoke(lockPatternUtils,null)));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isPowerButtonInstantlyLocks;
}

/**
 * This function is used to check the current userID
 * @return
 */
private int userID(){
    // myUserId is a hidden function in Class UserHandle that we want to use to return the current user ID
    String MY_USER_ID="myUserId";
    int userId=0;

    try{
        // android.os.Process.myUserHandle() is called to get a UserHandle instance
        // myUserHandle requires API 17, but it is OK, cause the function userID() will only be called at API 23
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            UserHandle userHandle=android.os.Process.myUserHandle();
            Method method = UserHandle.class.getMethod(MY_USER_ID);
            userId=Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(method.invoke(userHandle,null)));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Crashlytics.logException(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return userId;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Android 8.0: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.android.internal.widget.ILockSettings.getBoolean(java.lang.String, boolean, int)' on a null object reference
at com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils.getBoolean(LockPatternUtils.java:1198)
at com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils.getPowerButtonInstantlyLocks(LockPatternUtils.java:1252)`